# Link to propose tag wiki is broken from main tag view

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, tag-wiki

The "would you like to help us create it?" link to propose a tag wiki is broken; it seems to always go to 
https://english.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/@tag.Id  and this results in a Page Not Found error.

For example, when viewing [articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles), [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), [language-evolution](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution) (at this time these are all tags without a tag wiki), the text at the top reads like

> The [articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles) tag has no wiki summary, [would you like to help us create it](https://english.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/@tag.Id)?

The other links are working fine, both the "Propose Tag Wiki" button from [the About (info) page of these tags](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/language-evolution/info), and the "help us edit this wiki" link from the mouseover on the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed this, will be deployed later ... thanks for reporting it